# Как в unity сделать папку видную при компиляции проекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать папку с данными которая при компиляции будет находиться в папке с .exe файлом игры. Например будет папка "моды" с файлом с данными, при изменинии которых значение будет меняться в реальном времени, или при перезаходе. Зарание благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте новую папку "моды" в корневой директории вашего проекта Unity, поместите в неё ваши файлы данных. В Unity выберите эту папку в `"Project"`, кликните прав. кнопкой мыши. Выберите `"Asset - Mark as Asset Folder"`.

Comment: Премного благодарен.